# How to speed up this query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I used this query and it took too long for mysql to give results. The number of rows are 1.6 millions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TB.ID,  Latitude, Longitude,
    111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6-`Latitude`,2)
        +pow(106-`Longitude`,2)*cos(-6*0.017453292519943)
        *cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943)) as Distance  
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TB, `tablecity` AS TC, `businessestag` AS BC,
    `businessesdistricts` AS BD, `tabledistrict` AS TD, 
     (SELECT ID, 
         (SELECT Title 
            FROM `tablebusiness` As TBuild 
           WHERE TBuild.ID = TBB.Building) As BuildingTitle 
      FROM `tablebusiness` As TBB) AS TBuilding  
WHERE TB.City = TC.City AND BC.BusinessID = TB.ID AND BD.BusinessID = TB.ID 
  AND TD.ID = BD.District AND TBuilding.ID = TB.ID 
  AND (`Title` LIKE '%%' OR `Street` LIKE '%%'  OR TB.City LIKE '%%' 
       OR Country LIKE '%%' OR Tag LIKE '%%' OR TD.District LIKE '%%' 
       OR TBuilding.BuildingTitle LIKE '%%') 
  AND (-6.0917668133836 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 
       AND 105.90823318662 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.09176681338)  
ORDER BY Distance LIMIT 0, 100
```

Even though the number of rows are 1.6 million part of the query namely

```
AND (-6.0917668133836 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 AND 105.90823318662 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.09176681338)
```

greatly restrict the number of rows. It seems as if mysql doesn't bother optimizing the query by searching for

```
AND (-6.0917668133836 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 AND 105.90823318662 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.09176681338) first.
```

I changed the query by moving the latitude longitude aspects on the front

```
SELECT DISTINCT TB.ID,  Latitude, Longitude,
    111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6-`Latitude`,2)
        +pow(106-`Longitude`,2)*cos(-6*0.017453292519943)
        *cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943)) as Distance  
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TB, `tablecity` AS TC, `businessestag` AS BC,
    `businessesdistricts` AS BD, `tabledistrict` AS TD, 
     (SELECT ID, 
         (SELECT Title 
            FROM `tablebusiness` As TBuild 
           WHERE TBuild.ID = TBB.Building) As BuildingTitle 
      FROM `tablebusiness` As TBB) AS TBuilding
WHERE (-6.0917668133836 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 
       AND 105.90823318662 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.09176681338) 
  AND TB.City = TC.City AND BC.BusinessID = TB.ID AND BD.BusinessID = TB.ID 
  AND TD.ID = BD.District AND TBuilding.ID = TB.ID 
  AND (`Title` LIKE '%%' OR `Street` LIKE '%%'  OR TB.City LIKE '%%' 
       OR Country LIKE '%%' OR Tag LIKE '%%' OR TD.District LIKE '%%' 
       OR TBuilding.BuildingTitle LIKE '%%')
ORDER BY Distance LIMIT 0 ,100
```

It's still just as slow.

What should I do then?

Comment: Do you have indexes on Latitude and Longitude? If not then MySQL would have to traverse all the records to apply the filtering by latitude and longitude and this will of course slow down your query.

Comment: One thing that *might* help in speeding up this query, however unrelated to MySQL or query optimisation, is formatting your code properly when you post it for other people's attention. Horizontal scrolling is *very* inconvenient in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to include `tablebusiness` table in FROM clause three times? I have rewrited this one and used JOINs. Check your WHERE conditions. What is `Title` LIKE '%%'? Try this simplified query -

```
SELECT
  TB.ID,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  111151.29341326 * SQRT(POW(-6 - `Latitude`, 2) + POW(106 - `Longitude`, 2) * COS(-6 * 0.017453292519943) * COS(`Latitude` * 0.017453292519943)) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  JOIN `tablecity` AS TC
    ON TB.City = TC.City
  JOIN `businessestag` AS BC
    ON BC.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `businessesdistricts` AS BD
    ON BD.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `tabledistrict` AS TD
    ON TD.ID = BD.District
  LEFT JOIN `tablebusiness` TBuilding
    ON TBuilding.ID = TB.ID
WHERE
  (`Title` LIKE '%%' OR `Street` LIKE '%%' OR TB.City LIKE '%%' OR Country LIKE '%%'
    OR Tag LIKE '%%' OR TD.District LIKE '%%' OR TBuilding.BuildingTitle LIKE '%%')
  AND (-6.0917668133836 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 
    AND 105.90823318662 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.09176681338) 
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 100
```

Adding indexes on the fields used in JOIN and WHERE clauses also will speed up the query.

Comment: AWESOME. So I should use join. +1 selected as best answer. The reason by tablebusiness show up several time is because all buildings are businesses too.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for some part of the query is only possible with index. So you have to have an index. Since MySQL has extension for (geo)spatial data, you should look it up and use the R-tree index. That's the most efficient kind for range limit on two columns.

Comment: mysql has geo spatial extension? You sure?

Comment: @JimThio: Yes, [I am sure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have BTree index on Langitude and Longitude columns?

Answer (score 1):

What does `explain select ...` and `show create table tablebusiness \G` say?

There are some restrictions to how MySQL can use an [index for range queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/range-access-multi-part.html), be sure to read up on that.

In my experience for many use cases, in MySQL using b-tree indexes is more efficient than the spatial indexes.  I'd suggest changing longitude and latitude to be integers (multiply by an appropriate number to get the "decimals" and making sure you have an index that span both columns (`alter table tablebusiness add index latlon (latitude,longitude)`).

Comment: I think b tree is more efficient. But then I need to sort based on distance. That's where spatial would speed things up.